# Reading information to a map

Tags: java, eclipse, set, maps

I'm learning about Sets and Maps in the *Introduction to Java Programming* book by **Daniel Liang**. My professor has assigned a problem in the back of the chapter that asks me to create a program that:

- Queries the user for input on name
- Queries the user for gender

Using these two criteria, and this/these website(s):

```
http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/babynamesranking2001.txt 
... http://cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/babynamesranking2010.txt
```

I have to be able to get the ranking.

I'm supposed to get this information into an **array of 10 maps**. 
Each map corresponds with a .txt file/year. This is where I'm having problems with. How do I do this?

The (Int) rank of the student is the value of the map, and the key is the name (String) of the baby.

The way I was thinking was to create an array of maps or maybe a list of them. So like:

`List<Map<Int, String>>` or `<Map<Int, String>[] myArray;`

Yet even after that the issue of *how* I get all of this information from the .txt file to my maps is a hard one for me.

This is what I've come up so far. I can't say I'm happy with it. It doesn't even work when I try to start reading information is because I haven't specified the size of my array.

```
public class BabyNamesAndPopularity
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
      Map<Integer, String>[] arrayOfMaps;
      String myURL = "cs.armstrong.edu/liang/data/babynamesranking2001.txt";
      java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(myURL);
      Scanner urlInput = new Scanner (url.openStream());
      while(urlInput.hasNext())
      {
        ...
      }
    }
}
```

Would it be viable to make a set OF MAPS? I was kind of thinking it would be better to make a set OF maps because of the fact that sets expand as needed (according to the load factor). I just need some general guidance. Unfortunately the CS program at my university (Francis Marion University in Florence, SC) is *VERY* small and we don't have any tutors for this stuff.

Comment: Are you sure that your professor meant to read the input files from URL? I believe he wanted you to download those files and use those files as input.

Comment: Well, the book says vaguely to "use the data files to write a program that enables the user to select a year, gender, and enter a name to display the ranking of the name for the selected year and gender." So the method is up to me but I assumed reading them in would've been the best/most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

This answer rather vague, because of broad nature of question, and it may be more suitable for
`programmers SE site`. Still, you may find these two points worth something.

1. Instead of thinking in terms of 'raw' compound collections, such as lists of maps of sets or such, try to invent set of domain types, which would reflect your problem domain, and, as the next step, implement these types using suitable Java collections or arrays.
2. Unit-testing and incremental refinement. Instead of immediately starting with access to remote data (via `java.net.URL`), start with static source of data. Idea here is to have 'reliable' and easily accessible input data hand, which would allow you to write unit tests easily and w/o access to network or even to file system, using set of domain types from 1st point, above. As you write unit tests you can invent necessary domain types/methods names in unit tests *at first*, then implement these types/methods, then make unit tests pass.

---

For example, you may *start* by writing following unit test (I assume you know how to organize your Java project in your IDE, so unit test(s) can be run properly):

```
public class SingleFileProcessingTest {

    private static String[] fileRawData;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void fillRawData() {
        fileRawData = new String[2];
        // values are from my head, resembling format from links you've posted
        fileRawData[0] = "Jacob\t20000\tEmily\t19999";
        fileRawData[1] = "Michael\t18000\tMadison\t17000";
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Rankings rankings = new Rankings();
        rankings.process(fileRawData);
        assertEquals("Jacob", rankings.getTop().getName());
        assertEquals("Madison", rankings.getScorerOfPosition(4).getName());
        assertEquals(18000, rankings.getScoreOf("Michael"));
        assertEquals(4, rankings.getSize());
    }
}
```

Of course, this won't even compile -- you need to type in code of `Rankings` class, code of class returned by `getTop()` or `getScorerOfPosition(int)` and so on. After you made this compile, you'll need to make test pass. But you get main idea here -- domain types and incremental refinement. And easily verifiable code w/o dependencies on file system or network. Just plain old java objects (POJOs). Code for working with external data sources can be added later on, after you get your POJOs right and make tests, which cover most parts of your use cases, pass.

---

**UPDATE** Actually, I've mixed up levels of abstraction in code above: proper `Rankings` class should not process raw data, this is better to be done in separate class, say, `RankingsDataParser`. With that, unit test, renamed to `RankingsProcessingTest`, will be:

```
public class RankingsProcessingTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        Rankings rankings = new Rankings();

        rankings.addScorer(new Scorer("Jacob", 20000));
        rankings.addScorer(new Scorer("Emily", 19999));
        rankings.addScorer(new Scorer("Michael", 18000));
        rankings.addScorer(new Scorer("Madison", 17000));

        assertEquals("Jacob", rankings.getTop().getName());
        // assertEquals("Madison", rankings.getScorerOfPosition(4).getName());
        // implementation of getScorerOfPosition(int) left as exercise :)
        assertEquals(18000, rankings.getScoreOf("Michael"));
        assertEquals(4, rankings.getSize());
    }

}
```

With following initial implementation of `Rankings` and `Scorer`, this is actually compiles and passes:

```
class Scorer {
    private final String name;
    private final int rank;

    Scorer(String name, int rank) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
}

class Rankings {

    private final HashMap<String, Scorer> scorerByName = new HashMap<>();

    private Scorer topScorer;

    public Scorer getTop() {
        return topScorer;
    }

    public void addScorer(Scorer scorer) {
        if (scorerByName.get(scorer.getName()) != null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("This version does not support duplicate names of scorers!");
        if (topScorer == null || scorer.getRank() > topScorer.getRank()) {
            topScorer = scorer;
        }
        scorerByName.put(scorer.getName(), scorer);
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return scorerByName.size();
    }

    public int getScoreOf(String scorerName) {
        return scorerByName.get(scorerName).getRank();
    }
}
```

And unit test for parsing of raw data will start with following (how to *download* raw data should be responsibility of yet another class, to be developed and tested separately):

```
public class SingleFileProcessingTest {

    private static String[] fileRawData;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void fillRawData() {
        fileRawData = new String[2];
        // values are from my head
        fileRawData[0] = "Jacob\t20000\tEmily\t19999";
        fileRawData[1] = "Michael\t18000\tMadison\t17000";
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
       // uncomment, make compile, make pass
/*
        RankingsDataParser parser = new RankingsDataParser();
        parser.parse(fileRawData);
        Rankings rankings = parser.getParsedRankings();
        assertNotNull(rankings);
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to give a thorough response, Victor. I'm not following your second point (which seems to be full of useful help). I have only a layman's understanding of this material as all we've been doing in class is going over various data structures and algorithms. Specifically, I'm not sure how my IDE (Eclipse) works or what you mean by domain types. I'm assuming incremental refinement is just running a piece of code to see if it works, debugging, rinse, repeat? Again, thanks SO much for responding.

Comment: @PhillipRodgers Regarding unit testing in Eclipse, this seems to be a good starting point: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html. Domain types are, simply, types (`interface`, `class`) named in a way which makes sense for your task, so these names describe task in meaningful way. I've tried to show it in code above: `Rankings` and names of methods `Rankings` could have. Plus, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_domain